# Как экранировать одиночную кавычку ' одиночной кавычкой '?

Tags: php

> ... одиночная кавычка экранируется одиночной кавычкой вместо обратного
>   слеша

Источник: http://php.net/manual/ru/security.magicquotes.what.php

```
echo(''''); // ?!!! О_о
```

Comment: Про магические кавычки если что `Внимание Данная возможность была помечена УСТАРЕВШЕЙ начиная с версии PHP 5.3.0 и была УДАЛЕНА в версии PHP 5.4.0.`

Comment: @Visman Ну это вопрос не про волшебные кавычки, а про синтаксис языка.

Comment: Вы сами дали ссылку на источник. И такое экранирование работало только с волшебными кавычками при включении `magic_quotes_sybase`. Сейчас этого нет!

Comment: Если вы изучаете язык, то ориентируйтесь только на php7.

Comment: @Visman Всё равно ничего не понял.

Comment: Оформил ответом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> одиночная кавычка экранируется одиночной кавычкой вместо обратного слеша

**Нет этого в php!**

Работало ваше утверждение только при включении `magic_quotes_sybase`. Но все магические вещи удалены из php в версии 5.4, так как не отвечали безопасности.

**P.S.** Все это написано по вашей же ссылке из вопроса.

Comment: т.е. это было каким то внутренним устройством волшебных кавычек, не имеющим отношения к синтаксису языка?

Comment: Это устаревшая возможность. Сейчас в языке этого нет.